# Magento PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh Failing

Tags: php, magento

Im getting this failure on patching which im doing for a new customer but i dont know magento well enough to see what the issue is or how to fix it.

Anyone have any ideas? I actually have 2 patches im getting issues with:

Version 1.9.0.1

PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh

```
> sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh Checking if
> patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be
> applied/reverted successfully.
> 
> patching file app/Mage.php patching file
> app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php patching
> file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php patching
> file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php patching
> file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php patching
> file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php patching
> file
> app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php Hunk
> #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines). patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
> patching file
> app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php patching
> file
> app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
> patching file
> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml patching
> file
> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
> Hunk #1 succeeded at 31 with fuzz 1. patching file
> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
> patching file
> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
> patching file
> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
> can't find file to patch at input line 894 Perhaps you used the wrong
> -p or --strip option? The text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml |index
> 43698c2..f4fe5ab 100644 |---
> app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml |+++
> app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored patching file
> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml Hunk #1
> succeeded at 115 with fuzz 1. The next patch would create the file
> downloader/Maged/.htaccess, which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
> Apply anyway? [n] Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored patching
> file downloader/Maged/Controller.php patching file
> downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php patching file
> downloader/lib/.htaccess patching file
> downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml patching file
> downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml patching file
> downloader/template/login.phtml patching file
> downloader/template/settings.phtml patching file errors/processor.php
```

And  PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-46-45.sh

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-46-45.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 succeeded at 175 (offset -32 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 38
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git .htaccess.sample .htaccess.sample
|index b8821af..383313a 100644
|--- .htaccess.sample
|+++ .htaccess.sample
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Soap/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Exception.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 4202
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
|index 1633e89..ebad42e 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 4227
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
|index f1fd04f..95c6603 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 463 with fuzz 2.
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `.htaccess.sample` is missing in your project. Just get it from github (right click on this link -> "save link as" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/d0b97bacb84d061d98f7f765b9edf932d7ac6da8/.htaccess.sample ) and put it in your Magento root folder. After that you should be able to run the patch.

HTH

Comment: I tried that but still failing, i added the log here: any ideas? http://pastebin.com/U7RnMJ0q

Comment: Now it's telling you that 3 other files are missing, `app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml` and `app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml` and  `app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml`. Add them and rerun the patch

Comment: Yep starting to work out the logs on these, seems both iphone folder and modern folder were missing but just fixed it and worked :) thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your core files are not modified and all files are in place.

As patch will need this as a precondition for it being successful.